# Question from the proof of Jensen's formula: $\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_1) \cdots (z-z_N)}$ is nonzero at each $z_j$.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I am reading the proof of Jensen's formula from Stein and Shakarchi's Complex Analysis. 
However, in Step 2 of the proof below, I can't figure out why $g$ is nowhere vanishing in the closure $D_R$. WLOG if we consider $z_1$, then $f(z)=f(z_1)+f'(z_1)(z-z_1) + o(z-z_1) = f'(z_1)(z-z_1) + o(z-z_1)$ near $z_1$. So $g(z) = \frac{f'(z_1)}{(z-z_2) \cdots (z-z_N)} + O(z-z_1)$ near $z_1$. Hence I can see that $g$ must be bounded near $z_1$.

But how do we ensure that $g$ is nowhere vanishing in the closure of $D_R$?

For this, we need $g$ to be nonzero at each removable singularity $z_j$. But the removable singularity at $z_1$ should just be $\frac{f'(z_1)}{(z_1-z_2)\cdots (z_1-z_N)}$. So this is nonzero iff $f'(z_1) \neq 0$. But how do we guarantee this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$z_1,z_2,...,z_N$ are the zeros of $f$ **counted according to multiplicties**. That ensures that $g$ has no zeros. For example if $f$ has  a zero of order $k$ at $z_1$ the we are actually diving $f(z)$ by $(z-z_1)^{k}$ since $z_1$ is repeated $k$ times in $z_1,z_2,...,z_N$.

If $f$ is holomorphic in some disk around $z_1$ and if $f$ has a zero of order $k$ at $z_1$ then $f(z)=(z-z_1)^{k} h(z)$ for some holomorphic function $h$ with $h \neq 0$ in some disk around $z_1$. This is the definition of order of  a zero. [Note also that any zero of $h$ is automatically a zero of $f$ also].